# How to split connected and overlapping objects in binary segmented image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I've got an assignment in which I have to segment all the lemons present in the image and count them as well, I've successfully segmented all the lemons in image using OpenCV's inRange method but, there are bunch of lemons present in the image and they are overlapping so, in segmented mask all the lemons are connected to each other. I tried eroding the mask but in resulting image some of the blobs are vanished completely. Here's the code i used, original image, segmented mask and eroded mask. Is there any way i can split all the connected lemons and count them? Any help will be appreciated.

```
img = cv2.imread('lemon1.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_green = np.array([20,50,50])
upper_green = np.array([80,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
eroded = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations=2)
```

[image: Original image] [image: Segmented mask] [image: Eroded mask]

Comment: Instead of binary thresholding the image, I think you can try with edge detection, in that code you won't get any blobs, but the corner lines for each lemon in the picture. Ofcouse you still need to clean the edge detection results, but it should give you a good start,.

Comment: Thanks @ZdaR for suggestion. I'm thinking the same edge detection and then count them. Can you suggest what edge detection method is best suited for this kind of problem?